# How to send JSONObject with android volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to send something like:

```
{
 "username": "username",
 "password": "password",
 "email": "email@email.com",
 "usuario": {
    "municipio": 1,
    "estado": 1
  }
}
```

How can I do that? If I try with this code it doesn't work:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.AlertaExito, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", txtusuario.getText().toString());
                params.put("password", txtpassword.getText().toString());
                params.put("email", txtemail.getText().toString());
                params.put("estado", txtestado.getText().toString());
                params.put("municipio", txtmunicipio.getText().toString());

                return params;
            }
```

I think I should create a `jsonobject` but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with volley itself you can check its tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json (use the singleton from the previous lesson https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton).

There they are making a GET request but you can change for a POST with `Request.Method.POST`, the signature for the JsonObjectRequest is `JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)` found here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1b4858087f25a8033c5136a96b750752b87e128c/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java

If your problem is with your json, then just notice that JsonObjectRequest needs a JSONObject, so you can't just send a String, you can check the JSONObject documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and recreate the json through its methods or it also has one constructor which uses a String json encoded.

Comment: i don't know how to create my json object for submit it in getParams() method